# How to represent node weight in Gephi input?

Tags: graphviz, dot, gephi

When importing following GraphViz/DOT file in Gephi, the `weight` attribute is processed as a string value. As a consequence it can be selected in the partition tab, but not in the ranking tab.

```
digraph demo {
  x [label="x", weight=10];
  y [label="y", weight=1];
  x -> y;
}
```

I want to select the weight attribute in the ranking tab, so that I can set the node size based on the weight value.

I also tried to supply the weight values as string (`"10"`) and float (`10.0`), but this gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "… *the weight attribute is processed as a string value.*"

Possible workaround:

1. `Data Laboratory` > `Data Table` > `Add Column`.
2. Enter `Title` and select desired `Type`.
3. Select all records (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).
4. Click `Copy data to other column`, then select column to copy data *from*.
5. Select newly created column to copy data *to*.